# I need to calculate annual daily returns for 252 days of 30 stocks in a dataframe and print them separately

Tags: python, pandas

I have 30 stock's Adj Close price in a dataframe. I need to calculate annual daily returns and annual volatility for each of these 30 stocks

I need to do this operation for 30 stocks in this dataframe i.e. 30 columns

operation on one column is performed in the following way:

```
variance = data['Axis Bank'].var()
daily_volatility = np.sqrt(variance)
annual_volatility = np.sqrt(252)*variance
```

Is there a method to perform above operation in a loop for all the columns in the dataframe?

I Tried this loop, but its not working, i cant take these values in a variable

```
for columns in data.columns.values.tolist():
    variance = data[columns].var()
    daily_volatility = np.sqrt(variance)
    annual_volatility = np.sqrt(252)*daily_volatility
    print(annual_volatility)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think loop here is no necessary, get `std` by all columns and then multiple by scalar (if all columns in Dataframes is necessary processing):

```
df = adj_close.std()
print("Annual HDFC STD Daily Returns:", df*np.sqrt(252))
```

Comment: hdfc is just one stock, I need to perform the above operation on all the columns and there are 30 stocks ie. 30 columns

Comment: @the_learning_child - I change dataframe to another name, but it should working same like before.

Comment: can i iterate over every column to find the the above?

Comment: I think you didnnt get my question.. i need to iterate the above mentioned process iteratively overall the columns, and store the answers in a form of a list in a variable